# Python sum function... Does it add a hidden zero?

Tags: python

I have a class with a custom `__add__` method.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, example):
        return Example(
          x=self.x + example.x,
          y=self.y + example.y
               )
```

Now let's say I create two objects and add them.

```
example_1, example_2 = Example(4, 5), Example(2, 3)
example_summed = example_1 + example_2
print(example_summed.x)

# Outputs:

-> 6
```

Okay, works as expected. However in practise I have to sum a large, variable number of objects. So I want to sum them with `sum` function. When I do:

```
example_summed = sum([example_1, example_2])
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Example'
```

It's almost as if the sum function is trying to add an `int` into the sum. Presumably, if I'm right, it's adding a zero (addition identity operator).

So, why is this failing? Is there a hidden zero?

Comment: [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) uses a `start` parameter, which is 0 by default.

Comment: Python doesn't have a concept of [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). You have to supply the proper identity yourself to `sum`, rather than having some way of defining it in the type along with `__add__`.

Comment: `sum(xs, start=s) == s + xs[0] + xs[1] + ... + xs[-1]`. It *always* uses the start value, rather than only using it if there are fewer than 2 values in the sequence to sum.

Comment: If it makes sense at all to treat `x` the same as `Example(x, x)`, it might be worth doing so in your definition of `Example.__add__`.